# Same sub task appear as a milestone in Angular Gantt chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, gantt-chart

I have a angular gantt chart on my page. The plunkr is attached here.

[PLUNKR EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Gactr8zcZOgwMUfCnAV?p=preview)

What i am facing issue is that when i have a different tasks with same name under different milestones i see that task as a separate milestone.If you see the plunkr above then you can see that `task 14` is the task with same name under `milestone 1` and `milestone 2` with different date range but still 
i see `task 14` outside of the milestones as a new milestone. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have used the `children` array to relate parent milestone with its tasks. We can do it reverse to solve your issue.
Just relate children tasks with its parent. Use a `parent` field inside subtask.

```
 $scope.data = [
        {
            name: 'Milestone 1',    //name of milestone
             //tasks inside this milestone
            content: '<i class="fa fa-map-marker" ng-click="scope.handleRowIconClick(row.model)"></i> {{row.model.name}}'  // no need to send this from backend
        },
        {
            parent: 'Milestone 1', name: 'Task 11', tooltips: true, tasks: [
            {
                id: 'work_111',  //id of task 11
                name: 'Work 111', // display name for this task
                color: '#a61229',  //the time color for this task
                from: '2017-05-01T00:00:00',  //start date, it must be a timestamp
                to: '2017-05-31T23:59:00'  //end date, it must be a timestamp
            }
        ]
        }];
```

Please see the working plunkr that solves your issue. [WORKING PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/LTGMWOGhiyDpKMfd2UJj?p=preview)